# How to configure ubuntu to make GBK complie avaliable in eclipse?

Tags: ubuntu

I couldn't complie java file using GBK encoding in eclipse. there is no "GBK" option in properties of project,even though I have typed the "GBK" in "Text file encoding".

my eclipse is installed in ubuntu, maybe the default file-encoding of my ubuntu is utf-8. How to configure the ubuntu and let it support "GBK" in eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

default jre of eclipse is not sun's jre, I change it and success.